# How to use a material number as a feature for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I have a problem. I would like to use a classification algorithm. For this I have a column `materialNumber`, like the name the column represents the material number.

*How could I use that as a feature for my Machine Learning algorithm?*

I can not use them e.g. as a One Hot Enconding matrix, because there is too much different material numbers (~4500 unique material numbers).

How can I use this column in a classification algorithm? Do I need to standardize/normalize it? I would like to use a RandomForest classifier.

```py
   customerId  materialNumber  
0           1          1234.0    
1           1          4562.0     
2           2          1234.0    
3           2          4562.0     
4           3          1547.0     
5           3          1547.0
```

Comment: It's perfectly usable with a Machine Learning algorithm based for example on decision trees. With other algorithms like Neural Networks it's better to replace it with some meaningful features of the material.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can group material numbers by categorizing them. If you want to use a categorical variable in a machine learning algorithm, as you mentioned, you have to use the "one-hot encoding" method. But here, as the unique material number values ​​increase, the number of columns in your data will also increase.

For example, you have a material number like this:

material_num_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Suppose the numbers are similar in themselves, for example:
[1,5,6,7], [2,3,8], [4,9,10]

We ourselves can assign values ​​to these numbers:

1. [1,5,6,7] --> A
2. [2,3,8] --> B
3. [4,9,10] --> C

As you can see, our tag count has decreased. And we can do "one-hot encoding" with fewer tags.

But here, the data set needs to be examined well and this grouping process needs to be done in a reasonable way. It might work if you can categorize the material numbers as I mentioned.

Comment: But how can I find out whether the numbers are similar or not? I don't have something like material type, but the explicit material itself.

Comment: You have to review your data and decide for yourself, I can't comment on that without knowing the data you're using. If there is a documentation, you can use it or you can try to get information from the source where you obtained the data.